# Open list dropdown with click another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code about the dropdown select option, I have to try my code work when I click

```
<div class="field-placeholder"><span>Select Yuor Subject</span></div>
```

the dropdown will expand list option, but now I must double click on the same point, to expand option

I have tried using 
dblclick() 
mouseover()
but doesn't work

any idea
this is my work

https://jsfiddle.net/ravizikrillah/m6Lc5jwn/2/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I guess he wanted to open up the `<select>` with one click, but because of the "*placeholder*" on it, that was not working.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense.

Comment: (Yuor ==> Y**ou**r.)

Comment: Change `$(this).closest(".field-wrapper").find("select").focus()` into `$(this).closest(".field-wrapper").find("select").click().focus()` and get rid of `$(this).closest(".field-wrapper").find(".mySelect").click()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by adding one/two CSS rules and removing an event listener. Add the following properties to `.field-placeholder`:

```css
.field-wrapper .field-placeholder{
  /* ... */

  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

The `pointer-events` rules will turn off the mouse events on the element, so that's the one behind that will get it.

The `user-select` one prevents the user to select the element's content.

Then, you can removing the `click` event handler on `.field-wrapper .field-placeholder`.

```js
/*
You can remove the following:

$(".field-wrapper .field-placeholder").on("click", function () {
   $(this).closest(".field-wrapper").find("select").focus(); 
   $(this).closest(".field-wrapper").find(".mySelect").click(); 
});
*/

$('.mySelect').on('change', function() {
  var value1 = $('.mySelect').val();
  if (value1) {
   $(this).closest(".field-wrapper").addClass("hasValue");
  } else {
    $(this).closest(".field-wrapper").removeClass("hasValue");
  }
});
```

```css
.field-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.field-wrapper select{
  border: 1px solid #DADCE0;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.field-wrapper .field-placeholder{
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #80868b;
  left: 8px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 150ms cubic- bezier(0.4,0,0.2,1),opacity 150ms cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.2,1);
  transition: transform 150ms cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.2,1),opacity 150ms cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.2,1);
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  
  /* Add these rules: */
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.field-wrapper .field-placeholder span{
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}

.field-wrapper select:not([disabled]):focus~.field-placeholder{
  color: #80868b;
}
.field-wrapper select:not([disabled]):focus~.field-placeholder,
.field-wrapper.hasValue select:not([disabled])~.field-placeholder{
  -webkit-transform: scale(.75) translateY(-39px) translateX(-60px);
  transform: scale(.75) translateY(-39px) translateX(-60px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field-wrapper">
   <select name="subject" class="form-control-modified mySelect">
     <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Number (required)</option>
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>                                               
  </select>
  <div class="field-placeholder"><span>Select Your Subject</span></div>
 </div>
```